# How do I browse the WSO2 Jira bug database

Tags: wso2

I'm a developer and I would like to submit bug reports and patches.
I visit http://wso2.com/products/identity-server, click on Report Issues.
This displays the Jira Dashboard with a prompt to login and no other options.
How do I browse WSO2 Jiras anonymously, or how do I create a WSO2 Jira account?
How do I submit a patch and how do I track the progress to merge and validate it?

Answer (score 2):

You can browse WSO2 JIRA anonymously here:

https://wso2.org/jira/

I think you can register for an account here:

https://wso2.com/user/register

Submitting and tracking a patch is done through the normal JIRA process:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA060/Attaching+a+File

Answer (score 0):

register a user on wso2 (first link of @Chris) does NOT enable you to submitt issues in the jira-database (second link of @Chris). Recently I registered myself but still only have read-access to this one https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY